# Angular2 - DynamicComponentLoader Error

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to load another component via the angular2 dynamic component loader.

But I always getting the following error:

```
 Cannot resolve all parameters for 'MainComponent'(?, ?). Make sure
 that all the parameters are decorated with Inject or have valid type 
 annotations and that 'MainComponent' is decorated with Injectable.
```

My MainComponent:

```
/* ======================================================== *
 * > Imports
 * ======================================================== */
import {
    Component,
    DynamicComponentLoader,
    ElementRef
} from 'angular2/core';
import {LoginComponent} from './login.component.js';



/* ======================================================== *
 * > Main component
 * ======================================================== */
@Component({
    selector: 'mad-index',
    templateUrl: 'resources/views/index.html',
    providers: []
})
export class MainComponent {

    constructor(private dcl: DynamicComponentLoader, private elementRef: ElementRef) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.dcl.loadIntoLocation(LoginComponent, this.elementRef, 'login');
    }

}
```

Does anyone have an idea? :/

---

This is the tsconfig i am using:

```
{
  "disableCompileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "app/www/node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Why do you import `LoginComponent` from `'./login.component.js';` Isn't this supposed to by a TypeScript file?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer if i import it without the suffix *.js I get following error:
`Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading
http://localhost:1337/resources/scripts/angular/components/login.component(…)`

Comment: That's probably the root cause of your issue. There is something wrong with your configuration. Can you please add it to your question? (I won't be able to help here though because I don't use TypeScript myself).

Comment: check if you have transpiled file `login.component.js` in your project directory, if not, you need to transpile first

Comment: Sure, i will add the config to the question:

@A_Singh what do you mean with transpile?

Comment: little brother of compile, compiling ts files to js is called transpiling

Comment: try removing `"disableCompileOnSave": true` from `tsconfig.json`

Comment: To inject DynamicComponentLoader and ElementRef in main component constructor you should list them in the providers array

Answer (score 0):

Thou you have something weird set up in your config, that is not the source of this problem.
Both **ElementRef** and **DynamicComponentLoader** require proper inject in order to be resolved. Modify your constructor like this:

```
constructor(
    @Inject(DynamicComponentLoader) private dcl: DynamicComponentLoader,
    @Inject(ElementRef)private elementRef: ElementRef) {
}
```

As for your config, if you are using system.js you are probably missing something like:

```
System.config({
    defaultJSExtensions: true,
    ...
});
```